# clearSetTimeout, prevent setTimeout's from stacking up

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

I'm using setTimeouts in recursion to emulate setInterval, while prevent it from running over itself, example:

```
this.poll = function() {
    var self = this;
    if(self.timeout) {
          clearTimeout(self.timeout)
    }
    self.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      self.request();
    }, 1000);
}
```

`self.request();` contains ajax logic and calls `this.poll()`.

The problem is it doesn't seem to actually clear the timeout when `this.poll` is called again, and I end up with a ton of requests on top of each other.

Is there a better way to be handling this?

Thank you!

Comment: `self.request(); contains ajax logic and calls this.poll()` -- does `request` call `poll` immediately, or in its Ajax callback?  If it does it immediately, then I expect you'd end up with a ton of requests, because `request` is spawning a new Ajax request and then immediately queuing up a new one to run in the next second, possibly before the old request has resolved. (Unless your intent actually is to poll every single second.)

Comment: `request` calls `poll` in the ajax callback, the intent is to run every second.  However right now, if I refresh the page a few times, I get a bunch of requests at the start.

Comment: If you refresh the page, it kills the timeouts, wipes the JavaScript clean. What you are seeing is old requests from the previous page load.

Comment: Ahhhhh, sorry I had another call within my polling to request.

Answer (score 0):

Why emulate **setInterval** rather using a **flag** to prevent running twice at same time ?

```
this.poll = function(){
  if(this.running) return;
  this.running = true;
  var self = this;
  setIntervar(function(){
     var callback = function(){
        //your stuff 
        self.running = 0;
     };
     self.request(.....,callback);
  },1000)
}
```